# How to get manual camera focus in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Currently I'm using this library:
https://pub.dev/packages/camera and it has setFocusMode to either Auto or locked, but I need a way to be able to get manual focus mode for camera, where user can tap in camera feed and the focus should be adjusted accordingly.
How do I go about implementing this in my app?

Comment: hello, did you solve this question somehow?

Comment: I could not get a solution to this yet @АндрійГавриляк

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin https://pub.dev/documentation/manual_camera/latest/. Does this work?  you could use focus distance.  If you could get the distance of the object you could set it that way.  It's almost like shooting out a ray in game programming. I don't know if this is possible to do but maybe using the size of the objects in the image you could get the distance.  someone else has probably already figured this out.

Comment: The "manual camera" plugin is outdated and is not compatible with the current Flutter Camera plugin. It would be nice if we could update it or integrate its functionalities to the primary camera plugin.